# How to get all the Transactions from a block in NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have tried out the Apis - https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#changes-in-block but the experimental one does not seems to have long term support . Any Help please

I have set up a node as well but i am not finding the node Apis to query the node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are included in chunk, so you need chunks (amount of chunks corresponds the amount of shards).

So basically you're getting the block https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#block-details

```
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 id=dontcare method=block \
  params:='{
    "finality": "final"
  }'
```

Picking all `chunk_hash` from `result.chunks`

After that fetch each chunk

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#chunk-details

```
http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 method=chunk params:='{"chunk_id": "71gaCoF2vgDp2td2BWemSfrQkPNEaXqEiybZpt1k3doZ"}' id=dontcare
```

And in the `result.transactions` you can find all the transactions.

Comment: Alternatively you can request chunk with json params added recently

`http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 method=chunk params:='{"chunk_id": "71gaCoF2vgDp2td2BWemSfrQkPNEaXqEiybZpt1k3doZ"}' id=dontcare`

Comment: this helped , i had couple of other queries which i have riased in separate thread , could you please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299245/how-to-get-the-transaction-fees-of-near-transactions-and-which-operations-involv