# How to get the transaction fees of Near transactions and which operations involves Near amount?

Tags: nearprotocol

https://explorer.near.org/blocks/99qdUGNmGMMQQdKGmgA7Lf6PjaXAHgVVy53DLHJZpcbb

Block -  35866073 has 5 transactions

ChunkHash - GwMUrTgEfqEaV9s8ngvqUn9c4hi4G8Ywpggoy4VDwnok

5 transactionHshses

TransactionHash 2 - AMDbiQUJx2Dd9FfbaYYbNj2D6T6xPJMHgWCZ4RTrN1UU

Transfer from comchien.near to 85a577d5db02df7830c8ad3db76ca6a90dee6f176c8478eb12dbf30d8d2d54ee -  5.58572

TransactionFee - ? there is some transaction Fee shown in explorer but in Json structure i dont see the transaction fee , can you plese help how can i get the transaction fee

TransactionHash 2- 6Beo8SFyjPjjtFnT3b2aEGDHgPY9HxGZ17vWvpSN733c

I can see storage_deposit , near_deposit and ft_transfer_call. Does all the amount gets transferred to wrap.near. And same transaction Fees is missing in json struture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions in NEAR are just inputs. To see the outputs (execution outcomes), you need to query transaction details using [`tx` RPC](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#transaction-status) to see `transaction_outcome -> outcome -> tokens_burned` field. That is the transaction *initial* processing fee. Next, you need to fetch receipt execution outcomes (well, it is right there in the `tx` RPC response) and sum all the `receipts_outcome -> outcome -> tokens_burned`. That is exactly what [NEAR Explorer does](https://github.com/near/near-explorer/blob/c859b2bdc90c93da539380173dcce8388a67988c/frontend/src/components/transactions/TransactionDetails.tsx#L72-L83).

You also could find [this doc](https://github.com/telezhnaya/docs/blob/master/docs/tokens/balances.md) useful where I explain all balance changes there.